# OpenCV - haarcascade training

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

is it normal, that at stage 6 I have results like this? Sample percentage is around 0-3% at 1000+ features and FA is around 0.8. Would love to get some insight, also the stage 5 has only 50 used features while stage six has 1500+ and it keeps growing.[image]

Setting is like this, Iam training cascade to recognize faces.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, that I anotated my ROIs poorly and it was learning basically everything that was on the dataset pictures.